# Event Listener is acting like a program and is getting triggered right away and not listening for any events

Tags: supervisord

I need help with a usecase. I have two processes that I need to start using supervisord. These two processes should be sequential as the 2nd process is dependent on 1st process. Since supervisor, there is no means to do sequential execution. I'm using an event listener that should listen to process starting for 1st process (2nd process autostart is set to false), and then start 2nd processor using supervisorctl.

However the problem I'm facing is that the event listener is starting as a program and not as a event listener. Its not listening to events and just running directly. Also one more point noted is that the stdin input doesn't come to this event listener script, So I'm not able to track and write if conditions on what is the event. Here's an example of how I'm doing this,

```
[eventlistener:start_2ndprocess]
command=/usr/src/app/event_listener.sh
events=PROCESS_STATE_RUNNING
```

Please help.